# Can't fetch money from database

Tags: python, mysql, pysimplegui

I dont know whats wrong most likely a problem in the code, i have had my teacher look ober it and he can't se the problem ether

```
            if row_count == 1:
                    event3, values3 = bank_win.read(timeout=100)
                    bank_win_active = True

                    sql = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username =%s AND password = %s"
                    print(username)
                    mycursor.execute(sql, (username, pw))
                    myresult = mycursor.fetchone()

                    myid = myresult[0]

                    logg_inn_win.Hide()
                    bank_win.UnHide()
                    sql = f"SELECT  money FROM user WHERE username  ='{myid}'"     

                    print(myid)
                    mycursor.execute(sql, myid)
                    myresult = mycursor.fetchone()
                    print(myresult)
```

Comment: Could you please update your question description with what it is exactly that you are trying to do, where it goes wrong, and what the error message is that you're getting? Also, your question does not have anything to do with money in itself, so the question text is quite misleading.

Comment: Why are you calling `mycursor.execute(sql, myid)` if you `sql` variable has no parameters (note that you already substituted `myid` in the f-string, which is bad practice, by the way). Also, why do you do the first query (`SELECT username ...`)?

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in (all) variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: don't you get error message when you run in console? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you could open database in some database viewer (like [dbeaver](https://dbeaver.io/)) to check what you have in database. And you could use it to test your SQL query directly in database - maybe it will display some extra information.